# Proof involving correspondence theorem for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be a 2 sided ideal in a ring $R$. Let $ \psi : R\rightarrow R/I, \psi (r)= r+I $. I’m trying to show that the map $\phi $ between the set of two sided ideals in $R/I$ and the set of two sided ideals containing $I$ by $\phi (J) = \psi ^{-1} (J) $ is a bijection.
I have shown that this map is indeed injective but struggling with the surjective part. I have shown that if $K$ is a two sided ideal in $R$ (containing $I$ ) then $ \psi (K)$ is a two sided ideal in $R/I$ and so I just need to show that $\phi (\psi (K))= \psi ^{-1}( \psi (K)) =K $ but I am struggling to show this. How can I go about this? I already know that $K \subseteq \psi ^{-1} (\psi (K)) $ but the proof I seem to need $\psi $ to be injective to then show they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r \in \psi^{-1}(\psi(K))$. We want to show $r \in K$, as this will show $\psi^{-1}(\psi(K)) \subseteq K$. We know that $\psi(r) = r + I \in \psi(K)$, so that $r+I  = u + I$ for some $u \in K$. This means that $r - u$ is an element of $I$, but since $I \subseteq K$, this means that $r-u \in K$. Since both $u \in K$ and $r-u \in K$, their sum, which is $r$, is also in $K$.

Comment: Thanks. I just got this before you posted but nice