# Correspondence theorem between rings problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am looking at the correspondence theorem for rings. So if $I$ is a 2 sided ideal in $R$ and $\psi $ is the natural homomorphism from $R$ to $R/I$ then there is a bijection between the set of two sided ideals in $R$ that contain $I$ and the set of 2 sided ideals in $R/I$, namely $\phi (J)= \psi ^{-1} (J) $.

My question is, the proof involves showing that if $K$ is a two sided ideal in $R$ containing $I$ then $\psi (K) $ is a two sided ideal in $R/I$. When proving this part I fail to see how the condition that $I $ is contained in $K$ is necessary. My proof for this part seems to work even if $K$ does not contain $I$ but this can’t be true because $\phi $ is a bijection.

Comment: The proof for surjectivity requires it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387178/proof-involving-correspondence-theorem-for-rings

Comment: Yes I see this, but my proof seems to show that $\psi (K) $ is a two sided ideal in $R/I$ even if $K$ does not contain $I$. Is this true? For example if $K= \{ 0 \} $ then $\psi (K) = \{ 0 \} $ which is a two sided ideal in $R/I$. How does this not contradict the theorem?

Comment: It does not contradict the theorem: any ideal $K$ induces an ideal in $R/I$, but that will not give a bijection, only a surjection. If one wants a bijection, one must restrict to the ideals $K$ containing $I$.

Comment: What Captain Lama said. Notice that $\phi(K)=\phi(K+I)$ so if $I\nsubseteq K$, it could not be 1-1.

Comment: @CaptainLama Please consider writing it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider three sets: $A$ is the set of ideals of $R$, $B\subset A$ is the set of ideals of $R$ which contain $I$, and $C$ is the set of ideals of $R/I$.

Then as you noticed, $K\mapsto \psi(K)$ defines a map $A\to C$. It is not a bijection, but only a surjection, and the correspondence theorem says that its restriction to $B\subset A$ does define a bijection $B\to C$, with inverse $J\mapsto \psi^{-1}(J)$.

Sanity check: $\psi(\psi^{-1}(J))=J$ for all $J\in C$, but for $K\in A$, $\psi^{-1}(\psi(K))$ is equal to $K$ if and only if $K\in B$. All good.